# Hello! I am trying to set a line of a text file to a variable

Tags: python, text-files

I used an if statement to see if the variable assignment worked but I think I am formatting something wrong. I tried this with and without the \n. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
lines=[] #creates a list
file = open("gmail.txt", "r") #opens the text file
for line in file: 
    lines.append(line) #adds each line to list
file.close()
x=lines[0] #sets first item in list equal to x
print(x)
if x=="Hey \n":    #if statement attempt to check if variable assignment worked
    print("good!")
else:
    print("bad")
```

When running the code I get the following output

```
Hey

bad
```

Since the if else statement returned "bad" then I must not understand how the string is formatted when pulling from a line. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The text file contains

```
Hey
yo
```

Comment: `\n` is for newline

Comment: A newline is `\n`

Comment: Try following an intro to python tutorial. Any of them should cover this in the first chapter

Comment: So you want to read all lines and check if a given line is part of the file?

Comment: I want a set a line equal to x and use that string in an if statement.

Comment: Your comparison looks for a space between the "y" and the newline, which may or may not actually be in the file.

Comment: Are you adding a space between `Hey` and `\n` that isn't there in the original input? Highlighting your actual output shows no whitespace after `Hey` except for the newline.

Comment: Thank you! deleting the space fixed it! any idea why this was downvoted? I'd like to improve my future question asking. Thanks!

Comment: Well for one thing, it would have helped if you showed your txt file.

Comment: Is the current question any better?

Comment: For a first-timer, it's pretty good.

Comment: @JackGruber I wouldn't worry too much about the downvotes. You provided the code, explained what you did and what is the issue. Improved on request. Seems good to me.

Comment: Try printing it before any assigment and make sure you are on right track. Like 'Hey \n', has a space between both characters. Is it so in the file content too? Check it

Comment: Hint: use [`string.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.strip) To get rid of whitespace (like newlines) and then do the compare.

Comment: Thank you! it was just a matter of the "\" being in the wrong direction the first time. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking about how to read from a file. Here's the Pythonic way:

```
with open('gmail.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

If you want to save all the lines of the file into a list of lines:

```
with open('gmail.txt') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
```

A more generic way to create a list from something you were for-looping over is to use the `list` constructor. Here's an example.

```
with open('gmail.txt') as f:
    lines = list(f)
```